# ¿Cómo puedo modificar el código para que realice tres veces la misma función?

Tags: python, cifrado

El código cifra y descifra un mensaje saltando el número de letras que el usuario elija (Si escribes la palabra perro y el número 1, el mensaje cifrado será: QFSSP). Me gustaría recibir consejos u orientación para saber de qué manera puedo cifrar tres veces con el mismo procedimiento. (Para obtener el mensaje cifrado del cifrado del cifrado) El código está escrito en Python.

```
def main():
    mensaje = input("Introducir Mensaje: ")
    clave   = int(input("Clave 1 [1-30]: "))
    funcion = input("Encriptar o desencriptar [e/d]: ")

    if funcion.lower().startswith('e'):
        funcion = "encriptar"
    elif funcion.lower().startswith('d'):
        funcion = "desencriptar"

    procesado = encdec(mensaje, clave, funcion)
    if funcion ==   "encriptar":
        print(("Mensaje encriptado:", procesado))
    elif funcion == "desencriptar":
        print(("Mensaje desencriptado:", procesado))
        
def encdec(mensaje, clave, funcion):
    mensaje    = mensaje.upper()
    procesado  = ""
    letras    = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    for symbol in mensaje:
        if symbol in letras:
            num = letras.find(symbol)
            if funcion ==   "encriptar":
                num = num + clave
            elif funcion == "desencriptar":
                num = num - clave

            if num >= len(letras):
                num -= len(letras)
            elif num < 0:
                num += len(letras)

            procesado += letras[num]
        else:
            procesado += symbol
    return procesado

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
    input()
```

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Lo que puedes hacer es llamar la misma función `X` veces

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
for i in range(3):
    mensaje = encdec(mensaje, clave, funcion)
```

Donde `X` lo pones dentro de `range()` En este caso el código anterior se repetirá 3 veces

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta. Añadí el código que me compartió y al ejecutarlo, no cambia en nada la funcionalidad del código.

Comment: ¿En dónde lo agregaste?

Comment: Después del último return

Comment: Lo debes agregar en lugar de la línea `procesado = encdec(mensaje, clave, funcion)`